# Enable 'Clip to atlas feature' using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, atlas

I've tried to enable the checkbox  "Clip to atlas feature" on layout via PyQGIS. I've found this class: `QgsLayoutItemMapAtlasClippingSettings` but I don't understand how it works.

This is my try:

```
layout_clip = QgsLayoutItemMapAtlasClippingSettings(layout.referenceMap())
layout_clip.setEnabled(True)
```

but nothing happened.